# "Filter by tag " in Harmon.ie

Tags: harmon.ie

I am using Harmon.ie for SharePoint, but the filter by tag option is disabled.

How can I enable that?

I would like to know more about filter by tag option.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to connect inside a document library allowing tags.
Navigating into such document library will enable filter by tags option.

---- Jean